# HTML input type radio button not showing selection on page load

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

[image] 
I have been trying to get the proper input type radio button to select based on the value in the database on page load. It should show the respective button as selected, eg. if the file type is 'Delimited', the delimited button should be selected. I have verified the code behind that it works fine. I have also checked the page source that shows checked="checked" but the button still does not visibly show as being selected. I have tried it with a regular asp.RadioButton and that worked fine, why is it not working here? 
The code behind runs in the OnInit method.

### HTML

```
<div class="form__group">
    <asp:label class="form__label" id="switchLabel_FileType" runat="server">File Type</asp:label>
    <div id="FileType" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" style="width:100%">
            <label class="btn btn-primary btn-small active" style="width:33.3%" >
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="label_Delimited" autocomplete="off" runat="server" style="width:33%" /> Delimited
            </label>

            <label class="btn btn-primary btn-small active" style="width:33.3%" >
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="label_Excel" autocomplete="off" runat="server" style="width:33%"/> Excel
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary btn-small active" style="width:33.3%">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="label_FixedWidth" autocomplete="off" runat="server" style="width:33%"/> Fixed Width
            </label>
    </div> 
</div>
```

### C#

```
            string fType = row[Constants.FILE_TYPE].ToString();
            if (fType == Constants.FILETYPE_DELIMITED)
            {
                label_Delimited.Checked = true;
            }

            else if (fType == Constants.FILETYPE_XLS)
            {
                label_Excel.Checked = true;
            }

            else if (fType == Constants.FILETYPE_FIXEDWIDTH)
            {
                label_FixedWidth.Checked = true;
            }
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a relevant sample of the rendered HTML?

Comment: does that work?

Comment: have you tried in different browser?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it in both IE and Chrome.

Comment: This is what it shows in the page source.
<input value="label_Delimited" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$options" type="radio" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_label_Delimited" autocomplete="off" style="width:33%" checked="checked" />

Comment: Removing bootstrap class, fixes the issue...But it looks horrendous.

Comment: I guess you came to the same conclusion already, but the code works for me so the error is in your stylesheet, not in your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `data-toggle="buttons"` the checkbox dosent work that way you have to add active class to active that button

```
<asp:label class="form__label" id="switchLabel_FileType" runat="server">File Type</asp:label>
<div id="FileType" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" style="width:100%">
            <asp:label class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="Label1"  runat="server">
                <input type="radio" name="options"    style="width:33%" /> Delimited
            </asp:label>


            <asp:label class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="Label2"  runat="server">
            <input type="radio" name="options"   style="width:33%"/> Excel
            </asp:label>


            <asp:label class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="Label3"  runat="server">
            <input type="radio" name="options"  style="width:33%"/> Fixed Width
            </asp:label> </div>
```

and in cs you can set button by

```
        Label1.Attributes.Add("Class", "btn btn-primary btn-small active");
        Label2.Attributes.Add("Class", "btn btn-primary btn-small");
        Label3.Attributes.Add("Class", "btn btn-primary btn-small");
```

Comment: Removing data-toggle="button" converts it into a regular radio button.

Comment: I was hoping not to do that since the buttons don't look good with those circles.